# Select into query, insert fails, but the table is created

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2016

I tried to the following query.

```
SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT, 'A') col1 INTO #tmp
```

This query is obviously in error. Because it does not convert.
However, the temporary table (`#tmp`) is created even if the query fails.

Why? I think this is by design, but I want to know.

P.S. PDW (parallel datawarehouse) does not create temporary table.

Comment: I suggest this belongs on dba.stackexchange.com as its a very technical database question, not a programming question.